# Erro ao adicionar coluna na tabela 'users' laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Useu o make:auth e alterei a tabela 'users', mas sempre que tento cadastrar um usuário me deparo com esse erro:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateMatricula does not exist.
```

Este é o códido do RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required','string','max:255'],
            'email' => ['required','string','email','max:255','unique:users'],
            'matricula' => ['required','string','matricula','max:255','unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required','string','min:8','confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'matricula' => $data['matricula'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

E esse é código da tabela 'users':

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('matricula')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
```

Comment: No array de validação tem matricula também existe essa validação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já verificou o Motel? O nome é User.php, fica em app/User.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

É importante que se for adicionar uma nova coluna colocar no `$fillable` o nome da coluna, exemplo:

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'matricula',
    ];
```

Acredito que é esse o problema, eu usei esse site como referência: [techiescircle.com](http://techiescircle.com/add-extra-fields-laravel-5-registration-form/), e vi que você executou todos os passos, retirando o da view, porem faltou só isso mesmo.

Tem algumas vídeo aulas no site do laravel e também vi isso lá, é muito bom para aprender o básico até o avançado do framework, porem está todo em inglês e sem legenda, entretanto pode modificar a velocidade para conseguir acompanhar. Esse é o primeiro episodio [Laravel 5.7 From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/1).